# How to wrap the comma delimited values to the next line without disturbing the other fields using awk or ksh

Tags: awk, ksh

I have the following input, in which some of the values are comma delimited.   I would like decouple each value and print it in the new line.  I tried many ways in `awk`,  but no luck. If I have three comma delimited values, the first value should be retained in the same row, but the rest of the values should be wrapped up in the new lines.

```
Input File
===========
key1|0|11881|0|0|0|0|11769|0|0|0
key2|2027|345,712|0|1|0|2040|364,729|0|1|0
key3|0|670944|0|0|0|0|495554|0|0|0
key4|1847|1,21|0|0|0|1814|1,22|0|0|0
key5|1880|11,402|0|154|0|1886|11,397|0|151|0
key6|1,1,19137|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0
key7|1851|11,757|0|202|0|1856|13,751|0|193|0

Expected Output
================


key1|0|11881|0|0|0|0|11769|0|0|0
key2|2027|345|0|1|0|2040|364|0|1|0
key2|-|712|-|-|-|-|729|-|-|-
key3|0|670944|0|0|0|0|495554|0|0|0
key4|1847|1|0|0|0|1814|1|0|0|0
key4|-|21|-|-|-|-|22|-|-|-
key5|1880|11|0|154|0|1886|11|0|151|0
key5|-|402|-|-|-|-|397|-|-|-
key6|1|65|0|8|0|16684|51|0|8|0
key6|1|4570|-|-|-|0|4176|-|-|-
key6|19137|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-
key7|1851|11|0|202|0|1856|13|0|193|0
key7|-|757|-|-|-|-|751|-|-|-
```

#### EDIT #1

Per a comment left by @Avinash, here are my attempts.  I'm new to the `awk` world, so may be beating around the bush.  I followed the below steps.  Please suggest me if any easier solution if you have in mind too.  I am not getting the solution as expected.

```
step 1: $ awk -f test.awk a.txt > index.txt --> creates the index files
step 2: $ awk -f test2.awk a.txt > main.txt --> extracts the lines which are comma delimited and duplicate them number of times equal to the comma delimited values
step 3: $ awk -f updt_db1.awk index.txt main.txt --> updates the respective column
index.txt
=========
0|key2|3|345
1|key2|3|712
2|key2|8|364
3|key2|8|729
4|key4|3|1
5|key4|3|21
6|key4|8|1
7|key4|8|22
8|key5|3|11
9|key5|3|402
10|key5|8|11
11|key5|8|397
12|key6|2|1
13|key6|2|1
14|key6|2|19137
15|key6|3|65
16|key6|3|4570
17|key6|7|16684
18|key6|7|0
19|key6|8|51
20|key6|8|4176
21|key7|3|11
22|key7|3|757
23|key7|8|13
24|key7|8|751

main.txt
========
0|key2|2027|345,712|0|1|0|2040|364,729|0|1|0
1|key2|2027|345,712|0|1|0|2040|364,729|0|1|0
2|key2|2027|345,712|0|1|0|2040|364,729|0|1|0
3|key2|2027|345,712|0|1|0|2040|364,729|0|1|0
4|key4|1847|1,21|0|0|0|1814|1,22|0|0|0
5|key4|1847|1,21|0|0|0|1814|1,22|0|0|0
6|key4|1847|1,21|0|0|0|1814|1,22|0|0|0
7|key4|1847|1,21|0|0|0|1814|1,22|0|0|0
8|key5|1880|11,402|0|154|0|1886|11,397|0|151|0
9|key5|1880|11,402|0|154|0|1886|11,397|0|151|0
10|key5|1880|11,402|0|154|0|1886|11,397|0|151|0
11|key5|1880|11,402|0|154|0|1886|11,397|0|151|0
12|key6|1,1,19137|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0
13|key6|1,1,19137|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0
14|key6|1,1,19137|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0
15|key6|1,1,19137|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0
16|key6|1,1,19137|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0
17|key6|1,1,19137|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0
18|key6|1,1,19137|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0
19|key6|1,1,19137|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0
20|key6|1,1,19137|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0
21|key7|1851|11,757|0|202|0|1856|13,751|0|193|0
22|key7|1851|11,757|0|202|0|1856|13,751|0|193|0
23|key7|1851|11,757|0|202|0|1856|13,751|0|193|0
24|key7|1851|11,757|0|202|0|1856|13,751|0|193|0
```

## Output

```
0|key2|2027|345|0|1|0|2040|364,729|0|1|0|
1|key2|2027|712|0|1|0|2040|364,729|0|1|0|
2|key2|2027|345,712|0|1|0|2040|364|0|1|0|
3|key2|2027|345,712|0|1|0|2040|729|0|1|0|
4|key4|1847|1|0|0|0|1814|1,22|0|0|0|
5|key4|1847|21|0|0|0|1814|1,22|0|0|0|
6|key4|1847|1,21|0|0|0|1814|1|0|0|0|
7|key4|1847|1,21|0|0|0|1814|22|0|0|0|
8|key5|1880|11|0|154|0|1886|11,397|0|151|0|
9|key5|1880|402|0|154|0|1886|11,397|0|151|0|
10|key5|1880|11,402|0|154|0|1886|11|0|151|0|
11|key5|1880|11,402|0|154|0|1886|397|0|151|0|
12|key6|1|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0|
13|key6|1|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0|
14|key6|19137|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0|
15|key6|1,1,19137|65|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0|
16|key6|1,1,19137|4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51,4176|0|8|0|
17|key6|1,1,19137|65,4570|0|8|0|16684|51,4176|0|8|0|
18|key6|1,1,19137|65,4570|0|8|0|0|51,4176|0|8|0|
19|key6|1,1,19137|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|51|0|8|0|
20|key6|1,1,19137|65,4570|0|8|0|16684,0|4176|0|8|0|
21|key7|1851|11|0|202|0|1856|13,751|0|193|0|
22|key7|1851|757|0|202|0|1856|13,751|0|193|0|
23|key7|1851|11,757|0|202|0|1856|13|0|193|0|
24|key7|1851|11,757|0|202|0|1856|751|0|193|0|


$ cat test.awk
#!/bin/awk

BEGIN{
FS="|";
counter=0
}

NR == FNR {
for(i=1; i<= NF; i++)
{
  n=split($i,arr,",")
  if ( n > 1)
  for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
       printf "%s|%s|%s|%s\n",counter++,$1,i,arr[j]
}

}



$ cat test2.awk
#!/bin/awk
BEGIN { FS="|"
k=0;
}

NR == FNR {

for(i=1; i<= NF; i++)
{

  n=split($i,arr,",")
  if (n > 1)
     for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
            printf("%s|%s\n",k++,$0)

    }
}


$ cat updt_db1.awk
#!/bin/awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "|"
}
( NR == FNR ) {
    lookup[$1] = $0
}

( NR > FNR ) {
    key = toupper($1)
if (key in lookup){
    split(lookup[key], replacements, "|")
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        col[i] = $i;
    for (i=3; replacements[i+1] != "" ; i=i+1){
    j=replacements[i]
    col[j+1] = replacements[i+1]
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        printf "%s|", col[i]
    print ""
  }
  else
    print $0;
}
```

Comment: I have given the steps which I followed.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I moved that A up into the Q for the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sed` like this:

```
    sed 'h;s/,[^|]*//g;x
    /,/{s/|[^,|]*,*/|-/g;H;}
    x;s/-\([^|]\)/\1/g;P;D'
```

It wound up being relatively simple after all. Applying that little script to your data gets:

```
key1|0|11881|0|0|0|0|11769|0|0|0
key2|2027|345|0|1|0|2040|364|0|1|0
key2|-|712|-|-|-|-|729|-|-|-
key3|0|670944|0|0|0|0|495554|0|0|0
key4|1847|1|0|0|0|1814|1|0|0|0
key4|-|21|-|-|-|-|22|-|-|-
key5|1880|11|0|154|0|1886|11|0|151|0
key5|-|402|-|-|-|-|397|-|-|-
key6|1|65|0|8|0|16684|51|0|8|0
key6|1|4570|-|-|-|0|4176|-|-|-
key6|19137|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-
key7|1851|11|0|202|0|1856|13|0|193|0
key7|-|757|-|-|-|-|751|-|-|-
```

Basically `sed` just tackles each field from both ends. It first saves a copy of its current iteration to `h`old space. Then `sed` removes everything from every field following the first comma on. After that `sed` switches back to its saved copy so it can remove the field it just saved in the other buffer.

If commas remain it appends the second copy to the first following an inserted `\n`ewline character so it can recurse at least once more when `P;D` `P`rint then `D`elete only up to the first occurring `\n`ewline character in pattern space before starting over with what remains.

Comment: @Glenn, I used ur script as follows,  my task is accomplished, u are awesome, thanks a bunch, <ur script> | awk -F"|" '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s|",($i == "") ? "-" : $i; print ""}'

Comment: @janani - is this comment intended for me?

Comment: I thank to everyone who helped me to resolved the issue, of course u are also part of it, Mike :)

Answer (score 2):

I would not use awk for this, because I think it needs more flexible data structures. I would use perl:

```
perl -MList::Util=max -F'\|' -lane '
    $key = shift @F;
    @data = map {[split /,/]} @F;
    do {
        @row = map {shift(@$_) // "-"} @data;
        print join("|", $key, @row);
        $max = max map {scalar @$_} @data;
    } while ($max > 0);
' file
```

```
key1|0|11881|0|0|0|0|11769|0|0|0
key2|2027|345|0|1|0|2040|364|0|1|0
key2|-|712|-|-|-|-|729|-|-|-
key3|0|670944|0|0|0|0|495554|0|0|0
key4|1847|1|0|0|0|1814|1|0|0|0
key4|-|21|-|-|-|-|22|-|-|-
key5|1880|11|0|154|0|1886|11|0|151|0
key5|-|402|-|-|-|-|397|-|-|-
key6|1|65|0|8|0|16684|51|0|8|0
key6|1|4570|-|-|-|0|4176|-|-|-
key6|19137|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-
key7|1851|11|0|202|0|1856|13|0|193|0
key7|-|757|-|-|-|-|751|-|-|-
```

Comment: how to get this executed through my ksh script?  How can i invoke your code from ksh

Comment: a ksh script can invoke perl just like it can invoke grep or cp or ... anything. Just copy that command into your ksh script (change the filename of course)

Comment: I did, but getting this error.. Search pattern not terminated at -e line 5.
is there any issue with the command?  can you also please add comments to ur script which will be helpful to the beginners like me?