# How do I remove every number that's surrounded by <>

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, awk

I have tried this

```
sed -i '' 's/[0-9]*<>/g'
```

But it didn't work.

Example file:

```
<Number1>
</Number8>
```

output:

```
<Number>
</Number>
```

Comment: you want remove number or line?!?! Your question is unclear

Comment: I think the title makes it fairly clear.

"How do i remove every number thats surrounded by <>"
I even made an example.

Comment: Can we assume that the `<` and `>` follow XML formatting?  eg no nesting `<<>>`, and no un-matched `<` or `>`

Comment: Yeah, they are XML files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
sed -i 's/\(<[^0-9>]*\)[0-9]*\([^0-9]*>\)/\1\2/g' filename
```

Comment: your code have problem, test this: `sed  's/\(<[^0-9]*\)[0-9]*\([^0-9]*>\)/\1\2/g' <<< "<sss>asa1</sss>"`

Comment: Note that this works only if there is at most one sequence of digits within `<...>`. For `<a1b>`, it works, for `<a1b2>`, it doesn't. You need a loop within sed, if you want to handle the latter case.

Comment: @Uwe - you don't *need* a loop with `sed` - that's just one way. See my edited answer for an example of doing it another way.,

Answer (score 3):

This is really easy to do with `sed`, actually. You just get as many as you can in one go, then `t`ry, `t`ry again:

```
sed -e :t -e 's/\(<[^<]*\)[0-9]\{1,\}\([^>]*>\)/\1\2/g;tt'
```

I tried it with the following random bits of input:

```
<Number1>
234234 </Nu994845mb6er8>'
234234 <000000000000000000000000000000000000>>
<a1> 2 <34b5c> 6 7 def
```

And the results were:

```
<Number>
234234 </Number>
234234 <>>
<a> 2 <bc> 6 7 def
```

The regex just matches at least one number between a `<` and a `>`. It continues to replace that number sequence with nothing at all until it can no longer successfully do so. This is the purpose of the `t`est command.

Else you can do it *without* a loop like:

```
sed 's/^/>/;s/\(>[^<>]*\)*[0-9]*/\1/g;s/.//' <<\INPUT        
<Number1>
234234 </Nu994845mb6er8>'
234234 <000000000000000000000000000000000000>>
<a1> 2 <34b5c> 6 7 def
INPUT
```

#### OUTPUT

```
<Number>
234234 </Number>'
234234 <>>
<a> 2 <bc> 6 7 def
```

It will always skip any `>` until it encounters a `<` - so it only affects `<[^<>]*>` groups. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165078/52934) if you're interested in why.

Answer (score 2):

You either need a loop around a substitution command (possible in both sed and perl), or a nested substitution command (perl only). I prefer the latter approach; it's a bit more general:

```
perl -pe 's/\<([^>]*)\>/do{$a = $1; $a =~ s,\d,,g; "\<" . $a . "\>"}/ge;'
```

Example input:

```
<a1> 2 <34b5c> 6 7 def
```

Output:

```
<a> 2 <bc> 6 7 def
```

Explanation: The `-p` option says that we want to read the file line by line, execute the script for each line, and print the result (like in sed); `-e` means that the next argument is the script to be executed.

Essentially, the script is just a substitution command: We look for `<`, followed by any number of non-`>`-characters, followed by `>`. The `e` modifier after the trailing `/` indicates a special feature of the substitution command: Its replacement part is not a string to be printed, but again a command sequence to be executed. In this command sequence, we first assign the string between `<` and `>` (i.e., `$1`) to a new variable `$a`, then execute another substitution command on `$a` that simply replaces every digit (`\d`) by nothing, and finally return `<`, followed by the modified string, followed by `>`. The `g` modifier (both after the trailing `/` and the trailing `,`) means that the substitution commands should be executed for every matching string, not just for the first one.

If the opening `<` and the corresponding `>` can be in different lines, say,

```
<abc1
opt="def">
```

add the option `-0777` (i.e., `perl -0777 -pe '...'`), so that perl reads the entire file before processing it instead of working line-by-line (*slurp mode*).

Comment: Do i save the script as `script.pl` and then run `script.pl inputfile`?. I am not that experienced with perl.

Comment: If you want to modify the input file, you can use the `-i` option as in sed, i.e., `perl -i -pe 'PERLCOMMANDS' inputfile`. Without the `-i` option, the modified contents are written to standard output.

Comment: It might be better to slurp the input, OP doesn't state that the `<` and `>` have to be on the same line.

Comment: That looks more difficult than `sed`...

Comment: @mikeserv You're right, in this particular case, a simple loop arond the substitution is sufficient. I hadn't thought about this approach when I wrote the (former) first sentence. For other"replace this by that, but only in the following context" problems, the loop method can get very nasty.

Comment: but nested substitutions *are* loops, which are possible in `sed`. The `sed`der just needs to know how to delimit.

Comment: @mikeserv Sure, it's the same difference as between a global substitution `s/.../.../g` and a repeated single substitution. In theory, we can always simulate the former by the latter, provided that we introduce some temporary marking characters that prevent us from replacing the same string over and over again. In practice, we prefer to avoid that. Tasks like "append a zero to every number within `<>`" or "replace all zeros by ones and vice versa within `<>`" are easily solved with nested substitutions; with explicit loops they are not.

Comment: @Uwe - this is not what I meant. The nested substitutions *are* recursion - they imply that the regex engine must isolate nest, apply the `g`lobal substitution, and substitute its latest isolation into the original pattern space before moving on. While there is no such short-hand for doing this in `sed` *per se* - `sed` comes with two buffers for a reason. If one were to walk a series of globals down a path of singles, one could *more explicitly* emulate this behavior w/ little difficulty. [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164129/52934) is at least one example, and I can provide more.

Answer (score 1):

short sed way

```
sed 's/<\([^>]\+\)[0-9]\+>/<\1>/g' file
```

Comment: @mikeserv This answer does work perfectly for OPs example data. Maybe saying it would only work for one number would be a better comment.

Comment: @mikeserv Oki doke

Comment: You know what - my answer doesn't work either if `<` `>` span line boundaries, in fact. I guess, on second thought, you make a very good point.