# How to use sed to selectively remove leading zeros

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed

How can I substitute/remove `0`'s in this, using `sed`:

```
2001:0db8:03cd:0000:0000:ef45:0006:0123
```

to make it looks like this:

```
2001:db8:3cd:::ef45:6:123
```

There are 8 pieces of 4's divided by `:` in the middle.

The first piece of 4 must not lose **any** `0`'s and from the other ones, only the **leading** 0's can be removed.

Answer (score 8):

So you want to remove runs of `0`s, but only when they are preceded by a colon.

```
sed -e 's/:00*/:/g'
```

Comment: Thanks! And what if I want to remove all the 0's except for the first 4 characters?

Comment: @Pete You mean `2001:0db8:1002` → `2001:db8:12` (which wouldn't make sense with IPv6 addresses)? It's a bit awkward in sed. One way is to use a loop: `sed -e ': a' -e 's/^\(....[^0]*\)00*/\1/' -e 't a'`.

Comment: @SailorCire No, that wouldn't replace `0`s that are preceded by more than 4 digits.

Comment: @SailorCire you're right, it wouldn't make sense. I was just wondering if seriously those 20 characters were my entire assignment... Seems too easy but oh well.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: why `-e` ? Also could do `sed 's/:0\+/:/g'`

Comment: @Jidder `-e` is optional. I like to use it because it's more consistent with cases that need multiple `-e` options (using `;` inside a sed script doesn't work in all cases on all implementations). `\+` doesn't exist in all sed implementations.

Comment: @Gilles fair enough, just wondering.Which sed does '\+' not exist in ?

Comment: @Jidder I think `\+` only exists in GNU sed and BusyBox. It isn't a [standard BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03) feature.

Comment: @Gilles ah right, didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A similar approach using `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/:0*/,":")}1' file
2001:db8:3cd:::ef45:6:123
```

Comment: Shorter `awk 'gsub(/:0*/,":")'`

Answer (score 3):

If you're still interested in how to remove any zero except those within the first  4 digits, you can just do like:

```
sed 'H;g;s/\(\n\([^:]*\)\)*0*/\2/g
' <<\IN
2001:0db8:03cd:0000:0000:ef0405:00060:0123
IN
```

#### OUTPUT

```
2001:db8:3cd:::ef45:6:123
```

Ok, so this globally matches either zero or more sequences of a newline followed by zero or more not colon characters, or zero or more zeroes. The first sequence is split into two subgroups - one which includes the `\n`ewline and one which does not. The one which does is `\1` - but the subgroup which does not - and which replaces it - is `\2`. So the extra `\n`ewline character is dropped. And any zeroes matched which are not in that sequence are *not* saved at all - and so they also are removed.

The newline is only retrieved in the first place with `H`old - which appends a line to hold space following a `\n`ewline character *(which always starts empty)* - and then `g`et - which `g`ets `h`old space by overwriting pattern space.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the various machinations? Ta.

Comment: @jasonwryan - if it's not up to snuff, see [How to nest global matches with `sed`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165077/52934)

Answer (score 0):

would

```
sed -r '/^..../s/:0+/:/g'
```

be ok? (Improved answer from Gilles that keeps first 4 chars untouched)