# Remove a character between 2 known strings

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a data set like below:

```
\"XXX \ START sapiodj \\" aj \d 2387 END hddo\" START bbcc  \\" END ss
```

My Requirement:
I want to remove all occurrences of backslash`\` and double quotes `"` between START and END.

Desired Output:

```
\"XXX \ START sapiodj  aj d 2387 END hddo\" START bbcc   END ss
```

Note:

1. Multiple START/END in same line
2. I want to remove `\` and `"` only between START and END and nowhere else
3. And my file has multiple line (lines similar to what is shown above)
4. I have to use `sed` only

I tried something like below (was trying to get rid of `"` alone first) and it didn't give me the desired result:

```
sed '/START/,/END/ s/"//g'
```

Comment: I removed the asterisks at the beginning and end of your examples as I assumed they were intended for mark-up purposes. If I was wrong, please roll back to your earlier version.

Comment: Thx Joseph ! I am new to this forum, All that you are changing is exactly what I would have done too. Thx again

Comment: You got it. Welcome to U&L :)

Comment: FYI: `awk` or `perl` would have a much easier time with this.

Comment: I will be using this command on top of files in hdfs and I think  `awk` would ok too. No perl for now

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with hdfs so this doesn't explain to me why `sed` is a necessity here.

Comment: `awk` can be used. Some unix commands are not available in hdfs, I was not sure if awk was one of them. I just confirmed that both `sed` and `awk` can be used !

Comment: @JosephR. - Don't discount `sed` so quickly. I think it can do this easily enough, and I have a hunch it can do so more efficiently than can those others... I managed to squeeze the bulk of the work into a single `g`lobal `s///`ubstitution per line - though some prep and cleanup is necessary before/after.

Comment: @mikeserv One's man "easy" is another man's hieroglyphs, I guess :D

Comment: @JosephR. - oh come on - that's gotta be an exaggeration. The majority of the text is `END` and `START`! It just ensures there are no Ds between `END` and `START` then removes all `[\"]` that are not found between `END` and `START`. See the `l`ook output? If you've never used it before you should try it: `sed l` is what taught me `sed`. I stick `l`s in all over a script when testing stuff just to see what's going on as I apply edits. Still though, I kind of understand - the `awk` is hard on me too.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't have `` ` `` character in the file. If you do just change in the line bellow all `` ` `` to any other character that for sure will not be present in the input.

```
sed -e 's/END/`/g;:X' -e 's/\(START[^`]*\)["\]/\1/g;tX' -e 's/`/END/g'
```

Comment: You are relying on a specific character not being present. That is clever and pragmatic but dangerous - assumptions have a tendency of breaking things when you are not around.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks for suggestion, you are right, I made the answer shorter with `["\]` and by removing other unnecessary stuff. However using `\n` as a delimiter sounds too complicated for me, I've upvoted your answer though.

Comment: it may be more simply explained [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165077/how-to-nest-global-matches-with-sed) where the delimiters are already unique and single characters. I'm pretty sure the `{}` example in that answer is a fluke though - haven't revisited it lately. Anyway, I don't use it so much as a delimiter here as I do a spare character for offloading the actual delimiter. And mostly because `[^\n]*` is not portable.

Answer (score 2):

It's not too hard with `sed` really. You can always delimit a section with a `\n`ewline *or* you can trade out a delimiter for a `\n`ewline temporarily. *And* you can do it without a loop:

```
sed 's/$/START/;s/END/&
/g;  y/D\n/\nD/
     s/\([^D]*START\)*[D\"]*/\1/g
     y/\n/D/;s/.....$//
' <<\IN                                           
\"XXX \ START sapiodj \\" aj \d 2387 END hddo\" START bbcc  \\" END ss
IN
```

Sometimes you've just got to think about a problem a little differently. Instead of removing all of the `\\"` between `START` and `END` if we instead switch the problem around to how we might save `\\"` only if they occur between the head of the line and `START`, `START` and `END` strings, and the last `END` and the tail of the line it gets a little easier *(if, admittedly, not intuitively so)*. This is because of the way `sed` handles `*`zero-or-more matches in a [`g`lobal `s///`ubstitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165077/52934) context.

While the head-to-first-`START` bit will wash-out as a natural result of the rest of this, the last-`END`-to-tail bit does not - and so we need to append another `START` to the end of the line. After getting our extra `START` we then append a `\n`ewline character to every occurrence of `END`. And then with the `y///` transliterate command we simultaneously trade all `D` chars for `\n`ewlines and vice versa. The `y///` transliteration command, by the way, is not only very handy here, but is also more efficient than a `s///`ubstitution would be.

At this point a `l`ook at our pattern space would print:

```
\\"XXX \\ START sapiodj \\\\" aj \\d 2387 EN\nD hddo\\" START bbcc  \\\\" EN\nD ssSTART$
```

As you can see, now all `\\"` characters that need saving lie squarely between either the head of the line or a `D` and `START` strings and there are no `D`s between them. So the `g`lobal `s///`ubstitution that removes the unwanted chars - to include our extra `D`s - also replaces the ones that need saving with themselves. Last we need only to swap `\n` and `D`s again and remove the last `START`.

In this way you can reliably delimit fields with `sed` *no matter the input* and you need not rely on any not-occurring character but the one that is guaranteed never to occur on a line - and that is the `\n`ewline character of course.

When it has finished that prints:

```
\"XXX \ START sapiodj  aj d 2387 END hddo\" START bbcc   END ss
```

Comment: Clever to use the newline "delimiter"!

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/:/::/g;s/</:l/g;s/>/:g/g; # escape :, <, >
     s/START/&</g; s/END/>&/g;   # replace START/END with <>
     :1
     s/\(<[^>]*\)[\"]/\1/g;t1
     s/[<>]//g;s/:g/>/g;s/:l/</g;s/::/:/g; # restore <>:'
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe's|START.*?END|$&=~y/\\"//rd|ge'
```

Comment: you might drop the `t`est loop if you `s/\(<[^>]*>\)*[\"]*/\1/g`. The backref'd sequence won't squeeze in a global context - but you would probably have to handle the line's head/tail in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You have [indicated in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174815/remove-a-character-between-2-known-strings/174821#comment288697_174815) that `awk` is also allowed. So I'm basing my answer on this.

Assuming your `START`s and `END`s are balanced, if you split the line on either word, you find that you want to remove backslashes and double quotes from all even-numbered fields. To this end:

```
awk -F 'START|END' '{
                      for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){ # For each even-numbered field
                        gsub(/["\\]/,"",$i) # Remove " and \ from it
                        $i="START"$i"END" # Put START and END back around it
                      }
                    }' your_file
```

This assumes your implementation of `awk` has the `gsub` function which I can't vouch for.

As a side note, your `sed` doesn't work because it's basically saying "apply the substitution to the range of lines that starts with a line matching `START` and ends with a line matching `END`".